# Проблема присваивания значения C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Здравствуйте.

Вот программа: (**Visual Studio 2010 Express**)

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR * argv[])
{
    char *a = new char;
    printf("Enter a nuber:n");
    scanf("%d", a);
    printf(a);
}
```

Казалось бы, что результат должен быть равен тому, что мы ввели, однако нет, происходит что-то невероятное.

В чем может заключаться причина?

[image]

Comment: printf(a); - в этом причина. ;)

Comment: Вот исправленный вариант программы (правда без tchar'ов/tmain'ов):

      #include <stdio.h>
      int main(int argc, char * argv[])
      {
        char *a = new char;
        printf("Enter a nuber:n");
        scanf("%hhd", a);
        printf("%c", *a);
      }

Ввод кода символа и вывод этого символа.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to C++ world!

Смотрите, что у Вас получается. Сначала выделяете память под одну (!) переменную типа `char`, длиной 1 байт, и получаете указатель на нее `a`. Далее по этому адресу считываете из стандартного ввода одну переменную `int`, длиной минимум 2 байт (зависит от архитектуры и ОС). И scanf это благополучно и послушно делает. Уже здесь возникает опасная ситуация переполнения буфера (самая ужасная вещь в С). Далее Вы адрес этой переменной передаете в качестве первого (!) параметра в printf. В качестве первого параметра эта функция ожидает указатель на строку, т.е. массив типа char, оканчивающийся символом '\0'. Но у Вас там не строка, а переменная int в обычной своей записи. И ее функция начинает кушать. Пока не натолкнется на байт со значением 0. И при этом выводит всякие кракозябры.

Что делать?

**Вариант 1.** Стандартный.

```
int a;
scanf ("%d", &a);
printf ("%d\n", a);
```

**Вариант 2.** Экспериментальный, для изучения свойств переменных и массивов. Не повторять в реальной программе.

```
char * a = new char [sizeof(int)];
scanf ("%d", a);
printf ("%d\n", *(int*) a);
```

И никогда не передавайте в `printf` в качестве первого параметра строку с неопределенным содержанием. Это прямая лазейка для взлома программы, особенно на архитектуре х86.

**P.S.** printf, scanf - это все больше из мира С. В С++ их встретишь очень редко. Реально здесь почти всегда используются потоки cout, cin и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за столь развернутый ответ, всегда восхищался вашим уровнем знаний)

Answer (score 7):

1. Вы выделяете массив размером 1 `char`, так что два символа в него не поместятся и поведение *будет неопределенным*, т.к. окажется поврежден стек и далее может быть все, что угодно. В этом-то и заключается большая опасность работы с Си-функциями форматированного чтения/печати типа `printf/scanf` - **их следует избегать изо всех сил**.
2. На языке C++ можно решить вашу задачу куда более просто и безопасно:

   ```
   int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
   {
     int a;
     std::cout << "Enter a nuber:\n";
     std::cin >> a;
     std::cout << "result = " << a;
   }
   ```

Comment: Избегать изо всех сил ничего не надо. Надо просто **хорошо разбираться** в том, с чем работаешь.

Answer (score 3):

Все 3 автора правы только частично. Вы подменяете значение указателя через scanf. Нужно использовать оператор взятия адреса если нужно считать непосредственно в динамический массив.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
char* a=new char;
printf("Enter a nuber:\n");
scanf("%d",&a); //Взятие адреса здесь.
printf("%d",a);
system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: В плане указателей у автора все верно, за исключением того, что `sizeof(int)` пишется в аллокированный блок размера `sizeof(char)`. А вот вы передаете методу `scanf` указатель на указатель на `char`, что вряд ли имеет смысл.

Comment: @igumnov, вы не правы, т.к. переменная `a` - это и есть адрес динамической строки, так что конструкция `scanf(...)` у автора написана верно.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать Скорее всего мой компилятор расценивает это как адрес a[0], а не взятие адреса указателя а. Без амперсанда этот код не работает. Я только что проверил

Comment: @igumnov Да ну, не верю.

Comment: Да сейчас еще поэксперементировал. Такой код работает без амперсанда.

 char* a=new char;
 printf("Enter:\n");
 scanf("%s",a);
 printf("%s",a);
 system("PAUSE");

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать
http://s019.radikal.ru/i607/1210/53/aa36e93225c9.jpg

Comment: @igumnov, на лицо яркий пример *неопределенного поведения*, т.к. такая строка `a` не имеет концевого `\0`, то печать ее может закончиться чем угодно.

Answer (score 2):

Если тебе надо что бы выводилось число введенное тобой, а не символ который находится под этим номером, используй int а не char. 
Ну или замени

```
printf(a);
```

на

```
printf("%d", a);
```

Comment: Я бы с радостью, да `printf` не выводит `int`(

Answer (score 1):

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR * argv[])
{
    char *a = new char;
    printf("Enter a nuber:n");
    scanf("%1s", &a, 1);
    printf("result = %c", a);
}
```